# Nextjs middleware redirect

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I try to implement log-in/log-out feature. I use nextjs, redux-saga, mui libs.

*// middleware.ts*

```
import { NextRequest, NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { RequestCookies } from 'next/dist/compiled/@edge-runtime/cookies';

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!api|_next/static|_next/image|favicon.ico|robots.txt).*)'],
};

export default function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
  // const shouldExclude = excludedRoutes.some((route) => req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith(route));

  if (isStaticAsset(req)) {
    return NextResponse.next();
  }

  const cookies: RequestCookies = req.cookies;
  const authHeader = cookies.get('access_token')?.value;
  console.log('authHeader', authHeader);

  // Check if the request is already for the login page
  const isLoginPage = req.nextUrl.pathname === '/authentication/login';

  if (!authHeader && !isLoginPage) {
    const redirectUrl = new URL('/authentication/login', req.nextUrl.origin).toString();
    return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
  }

  // if everything is good, user is authenticated

  return NextResponse.next();
}

function isStaticAsset(req: NextRequest) {
  const extensions = ['.js', '.css', '.png', '.jpg', '.jpeg', '.gif', '.svg'];
  const requestPath = req.nextUrl.pathname.toLowerCase();
  return extensions.some((extension) => requestPath.endsWith(extension));
}
```

*// authSaga*

```
...imports;

function* handleLogin(action: { payload: { email: string; password: string } }) {
  try {
    const { data } = yield call(logInRequest, action.payload);
    const res = data.data;
    if (res && res.new_token) {
      yield call(setAuthCookies, res.new_token, res.user);
      yield put(logInUserSucceed(res.user));
      yield put(
        showAlertSuccess('Successful log-in', {
          autoClose: true,
          keepAfterRouteChange: false,
        })
      );
      Router.push('/');
    } else {
      yield put(logInUserFailed());
    }
  } catch (error: any) {
    yield put(
      showAlertError(error.message, {
        autoClose: true,
        keepAfterRouteChange: false,
      })
    );
    yield put(logInUserFailed(error.message));
  }
}

// Wrap setting cookies into a saga that resolves a promise once cookies are set
function* setAuthCookies(token: string, user: any) {
  return new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    try {
      Cookies.set('access_token', token);
      Cookies.set(
        'userData',
        JSON.stringify({
          firstname: user.firstname,
          lastname: user.lastname,
        } as any)
      );
      resolve();
    } catch (e) {
      reject(e);
    }
  });
}

const authSagas = [takeLatest(logInUser, handleLogin)];

export default authSagas;
```

The issue is in redirecting after log-in. I've used 2 approaches:

1. First one, as you can see in authSaga, after `yield put(logInUserSucceed(res.user))` action I've tried to redirect to the main page - Router.push('/'). But after the request is sent it just doesn't redirect and I get from the logs this:

```
_app-0a3d7719cd0aa2c8.js:87 Starting to change to /
_app-0a3d7719cd0aa2c8.js:87 Starting to change to /authentication/login
_app-0a3d7719cd0aa2c8.js:87 Finished changing to /authentication/login
```

it seems that when I set the cookie in saga and try to '/' route, the middleware in server-side checks the cookies before setting and change the route back to the /authentication/login.
2) Second one, I've just moved the router.push('/') logic to the AuthLogin component inside the useEffect(). I push to the main page only after the **isAuthenticated** flag is true, I set it after the **logInSucceed** action. And I get infinite loop, where router pushes to the ('/') route and middleware does the same by redirecting back to the /authentication/login route:

*// AuthLogin.ts*

```
const AuthLogin = ({ title, subtitle, subtext, logInUser, authData }: loginType) => {
  const {
    handleSubmit,
    control,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useYupValidationForm<FormData>(schema);
  const router = useRouter();
  const { isAuthenticated } = authData;

  const onSubmit = (data: FormData) => {
    // console.log(data);
    logInUser(data);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (isAuthenticated && router.pathname !== '/') {
      router.push('/');
    }
  }, [isAuthenticated]);

return (
---rest elements
<Button
          color="primary"
          variant="contained"
          sx={{ textTransform: 'uppercase', fontWeight: 600 }}
          size="large"
          fullWidth
          type="submit"
          disabled={isAuthenticated}
        >
          Войти
        </Button>
----
);
```

To resolve this problem I just changed the **window.location.href** to the '/', after the logInSucceed() action. And removed useEffect in **AuthLogin** component and Router.push in saga. But it reloads this main route, I don't want to reload the page.

Overall, is it a normal approach to use nextjs built-in middleware for such a purpose?
If it is okay, I would like to find out how to properly check the routes and solve this problem finally.

Of course, If there are other best practices to do my task, I'm fully open to your pieces of advice and suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the problem might be with the client cache. Next.js by default prefetches page to improve UX in navigation. So, if the user was already on a private page (e.g. "Home") and then was redirected to "Authorization" page, after that he was authorized and redirected to a cached (possibly) version of the previously visited private page ("Home" page). That's why the trick with redirect to "other" page worked in your case (but what if an unauthorized user goes to that "other" page first and then gets redirected to the "Authorization" page? Will he get the same result as before?). Also the `window.location.href` solution helped you as it cleared the entire client cache.

I don't know what Next.js and router you are using, so in case of `PagesRouter` you can do something like this:

```
router.push(urlToRedirect, undefined, {
    unstable_skipClientCache: true,
});
```

Unfortunately, you can't disable prefetching for all possible cases (setting the `Link` `prefetch` prop to "false" will not disable prefetching on a "hover" event).

You can find several discussions on this topic here, but you can also find some working solutions here:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/pull/37299
- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/24009

For a new `AppRouter`, you can't pass the `unstable_skipClientCache` param to the `push` method, but you can completely disable prefetching for the `Link`:

- https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/24437#discussioncomment-3752350

Hope this helps you find a way to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think the code inside `if` is not setting the cookie properly:

```
if (res && res.new_token) {
  // check browser tools if you set the cookie correctly
  yield call(setAuthCookies, res.new_token, res.user);
  yield put(logInUserSucceed(res.user));
  yield put(
    showAlertSuccess('Successful log-in', {
      autoClose: true,
      keepAfterRouteChange: false,
    })
  );
```

When `Router.push('/');` executes, this is a request to a page route, so middleware runs and since if statement above is not functioning well, you are redirecting to `/authentication/login` because this code in middleware executes

```
if (!authHeader && !isLoginPage) {
    const redirectUrl = new URL('/authentication/login', req.nextUrl.origin).toString();
    return NextResponse.redirect(redirectUrl);
  }
```

Comment: you know mate, I also thought about it and I actually mentioned this theory.
But I changed the Router.push("/") to Router.push("/other-page") and it worked!
Now, I'm guessing that it is because of the root route  "/" requests all the pages and that's why my condition `!authHeader && !isLoginPage` goes after the Router.push("/") , so middleware sees that one of the first requested page is not '/authentication/login' and redirects me back to the '/authentication/login'. 
What do you think about that? I think now you would say the same:)